# android linking string_array to textview

Tags: android

I have a strings.xml with a string-array resource.   In another .xml I have a textview.  setText() doesnt accept an array so how do I make my string array appear in the textview?  I've done a search but can't seem to find something which addresses this issue.  It is such a simple matter that I think I must be missing the obvious.
Ron

Answer (score 0):

You can not refer to String Array resource in XML:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Check `RESOURCE REFERENCE` for both String and String Array resources. You can refer to String resource in XML, but you can not refer to String Array and Plurals resources.

Comment: Yeah it would be nice if you could i.e. @stringarray/nameOfArray[0] using this in a layout.xml file... seems a fundamental thing that android missed

Comment: However it is possible for spinners using android:entries --> 
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/country_prompt" />